# Is this question really opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, opinion-based

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Should Redux Saga be learned in 2023?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74929239/should-redux-saga-be-learned-in-2023)

Sure asking if someone is worth learning or not is opinion-based, but is it really opinion-based asking if learning a technology that is discouraged by a Redux Saga developer maintainer himself, and also quoted to be deprecated really opinion-based?

I looked up on the Internet if it was worthwhile and its supposedly deprecation and the only thing I found out was exactly [this question on Stack Overflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72360331/is-it-worth-using-redux-saga-in-long-term?rq=1#:%7E:text=Such%20a%20powerful%20%26%20elegant%20tool,starting%20from%20Jan%2027%2C%202021.)) (which **also** could be considered a opinion-based question, but for some reason it wasn't), the most recent information. All the rest dates from 2021, and I just wanted to know the state of it currently.

If it's not a proper question to ask here, then where could I ask such a question?

Comment: [their github](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/2298) seems to clear this up.

Comment: Doesn't seem to clear anything up, @Warcupine. They confirm that the latest update was 3 years ago, then, when asked if it's still reliable to use, the answer is "No worries". That's not in any way an answer to the question that was asked. Later, after it was closed, there's an answer stating that it will continue to be maintained, but... how does that square with the original comment that says it hasn't been updated in 3 years?

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe I should have just linked to the general github, it appears they are updating it, I see commits in the last few months. Either way, that is where this should be asked probably.

Comment: And the plot thickens: the commenter who says that the "library will go on ... being maintained" (Helpico) doesn't even appear to be associated with the project as a developer or maintainer! So, why would their word be authoritative?

Comment: "Sure asking if someone is worth learning or not is opinion-based" - and that's what you've asked, both in the question title and in the body. So yes, your question is opinion-based.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, both questions are opinion-based and not suitable for Stack Overflow.

> Sure asking if someone is worth learning or not is opinion-based…

Yes, I'm glad that is obvious to you.

> …but is it really opinion-based asking if learning a technology that is discouraged by a Redux Saga developer maintainer himself, and also quoted to be deprecated really opinion-based?

Why would that make any difference? If it's opinion-based to ask if something is worth learning, then it's opinion-based to ask if something is worth learning regardless of the concerns that might make it worth or not worth learning.

> If it's not a proper question to ask here, then where could I ask such question?

No idea. All I can tell you is that it doesn't belong here. You don't go to the theatre and ask where you can buy a car, do you?

Comment: Stackoverflow is place for making questions, and there are plenty of versions of this platform. It shouldn't be of a surprise to see someone asking "where should I ask X thing".

Comment: Saying that Stack Overflow is a place for asking questions is like saying that an auto-parts store is a place for buying things. Yes, it is, but I guarantee that you will be very disappointed if you go into an auto-parts store trying to buy milk, bread, or bananas. Same thing for Stack Overflow: we only allow [*specific kinds of questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If your question doesn't fit within those constraints, then it isn't accepted here.

Comment: If you're thinking that there might be another Stack Exchange site where opinion-based questions are allowed, and we might be able to recommend that, then, no. Opinion-based questions like these are not allowed on any Stack Exchange site; that's the whole point of a Q&A site. This is something we attempt to explain in the [tour]: "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers." You'll find SE sites that cover all sorts of *topics*, like cooking and parenting, but they're still Q&A.

Comment: @AmodeusR "Stackoverflow is place for making questions" - no it is a place for searching for answers. The exact opposite. Asking questions is a last resort.

Comment: @Gimby and what do you need to do to find answers?...

Comment: @AmodeusR use Google or your favourite equivalent. You set yourself up for that response. I know what you're evasively trying to get at but the site has been up for over a decade, let's not pretend that the question you want to ask has not been asked and answered at least a dozen times before. I have not had to ask a question yet myself.

Answer (score 1):

> ...is it really opinion-based asking if learning a technology that is discouraged by a Redux Saga developer maintainer himself, and also quoted to be deprecated really opinion-based?

Doesn't this answer the question already? Either that's definitive proof that it's not worth learning and the question is pointless, or it's not definitive proof and the question is still opinion-based.

Comment: The matter is that reference is 7 months old, and the comment on the deprecation I didn't find anywhere else other than in that question, so only having a vague statement made months ago, no, it doesn't necessarily answer itself or anything.